# Iphone simulator hangs while installing apps

Tags: ios-simulator

I am using snow leopard, xcode 3.22, i first had this issue when i was using os 4 beta, i have removed the xcode software from my system and reinstalled.  I can't get any app to load in the simulator, the app starts to install in the simulator then nothing, I can install the app to my device, but i can run anything in the simulator it just hangs, i am not sure what to do

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it drove me nuts. I finally figured it out.

Make sure that "/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator" is owned by your user id and that it is also writable by you. All the subfolders should also be owned and be writable by you.

Once I changed ownership of "/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator" to me everything worked.

Comment: Note that this refers to the "Library" folder in your home directory, not the system "/Library" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. The simulator launches but stays on a blank screen. Then when I press "stop" in Xcode it doesn't stop. I have to force quit Xcode. I've tried many solutions including reinstalling Xcode.

Ultimately, the only thing that worked was changing the debugger from LLDB to GDB in the scheme. I don't know why this works.